# Cómo verificar el permiso PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS en Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-permissions

Estoy realizando una app que usa el permiso especial `android.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS` que en principio no se puede solicitar directamente al usuario, lo debe de permitir entrando en la ventana de configuración:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para solicitar esa ventana directamente uso

```
startActivity(Intent(Settings.ACTION_USAGE_ACCESS_SETTINGS).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NO_HISTORY))
```

Lo que no se como realizar es la comprobación de ese permiso, como es un permiso especial con el manejo de permisos no pasa la comprobación

Answer (score 2, accepted):

El final buscando por la red y de diferentes hilos he confeccionado la siguiente función *hasPermissionPackageUsageStats()* devuelve el valor dependiendo lo que esté especificado en la ventana de configuración del dispositivo android.

```
    private fun hasPermissionPackageUsageStats(): Boolean {
        val appOpsManager = this.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE) as AppOpsManager
        val mode = appOpsManager.checkOpNoThrow(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_GET_USAGE_STATS, Process.myUid(), this.packageName)

        return if (mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_DEFAULT) {
            this.checkCallingOrSelfPermission(Manifest.permission.PACKAGE_USAGE_STATS) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
        } else {
            mode == AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED
        }
    }
```